# C# VSTO Project change from Excel 2010 to Excel 2007

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a solution in VS2010 that was developed as an Excel 2007 add-in. Unfortunately something happened with my profile and since then VS runs the solution with Excel 2010. Somehow my profile got corrupted and my VS solution got corrupted too changing the Office library from 2007 to 2010. I tried changing the library back to 2007 but every time I open the VS solution VS changes it. Anyone has an idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have installed **Office 2010** which forces VS.NET to use the **Office 14 PIAs**. You can still deploy your add-in to **Office 2007**, you just have to be sure you don't use any **Office 2010** specific features.

Also see [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10602014/175679) .

Comment: I have installed Office 2010 and Excel 2007 so that I can develop plugins in both. A few days ago I was able to develop in both platforms but suddenly after some windows updates this stopped working.